# Android, showProgress() and hideProgress() properly

Tags: android, mvp, android-mvp

I'm new on android development, so decided to learn simple login using MVP architectural pattern, in general everything is working fine, as checking user credentials, calling repository...etc.

However, only the implementations of showProgress() & hideProgress() that works in a weird way, for me at least.
Note that the `showProgress()` only works if the user inter valid credentials.

Thanks.

```
// Presenter Class
package com.example.mvp.login;

import android.util.Log;

import com.example.mvp.login.LoginContract;
import com.example.mvp.utils.SharedPrefManager;

public class LoginPresenterImpl implements LoginContract.Presenter{

    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;

    private LoginContract.View view;
    private LoginContract.Service service;

    public LoginPresenterImpl(LoginContract.View view, LoginContract.Service service) {
        this.view = view;
        this.service = service;
        sharedPrefManager = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(view.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginClicked() {

        String username = view.getUsername();
        if (username.isEmpty()){
            view.showUsernameError();
            view.hideProgress();
            return;
        }

        String password = view.getPassword();
        if (password.isEmpty()){
            view.showPasswordError();
            view.hideProgress();
            return;
        }

        view.showProgress(); // this method is called, but doesn't show in the UI Thread
        boolean loginSucceeded = service.login(username, password);
        if (loginSucceeded){
            sharedPrefManager.userLogin(username);
            view.navigateHome();
            return;
        }

        view.hideProgress();
        view.showLoginError();
    }

    @Override
    public void isUserLoggedIn() {
        if(sharedPrefManager.isLoggedIn())
            view.navigateHome();
    }
}
```

```
// View Class
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginContract.View{

    private EditText ed_username, ed_password;
    private Button login;
    private TextView signUp;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    LoginContract.Presenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        initView(this);
        presenter = new LoginPresenterImpl(this, new LoignServiceImpl());
        presenter.isUserLoggedIn();

        login.setOnClickListener(click);
    }

    View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.login:
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            presenter.onLoginClicked();
                        }
                    }, 1200);
            }
        }
    };

    public void initView(LoginActivity view){
        ed_username = view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        ed_password = view.findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = view.findViewById(R.id.login);
        signUp = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return ed_username.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return ed_password.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void showProgress() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgress() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void showUsernameError() {
        ed_username.setError("Must not be empty");
    }

    @Override
    public void showPasswordError() {
        ed_password.setError("Must not be empty");
    }

    @Override
    public void navigateHome() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void showLoginError() {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "User not Found",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Assuming that `service.login(username, password);` is a network call (asynchronous) you won't see the progress because code executes and hides the progress, it won't wait for the call to complete.

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3 , the question is how to implement showProgress() and hideProgress properly in the UI Thread.

Comment: What does `service.login(username, password);` do?

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3 , service.login(username, password); checks username and password against a repository(which is hard-coded for now) and return boolean type result "true if use exists, false otherwise". this part is working fine.

Comment: If service returns the result immediately, I don't really see how you want to show and hide the progress bar. If it's still in development process, you should consider returning the result after a delay, so you should be able to see the progress bar.

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3, and " Ionut J. Bejan ". Thank you both for your information. I wish that i can vote for your comments, as an appreciation  for your informations.

Comment: @Ionut J. Bejan, and " h4rd4r7c0r3 ". Thank you both for your information. I wish that i can vote for your comments, as an appreciation  for your informations.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ***h4rd4r7c0r3*** and ***Ionut J. Bejan***, for highlighting several aspects i wasn't a ware of, in particular Working Thread(UI THREAD) and Another Thread(Background Thread).

Although i don't know yet  how to implement them very well, i found way after searching the internet.

The main scenario are:

1. When the user enter username and password, UI should show indication
   (Progress Bar) checking credentialiy of the user, implementing
   `showProgress()`.
2. When the checking is finished, UI should stop the indication.
   implementing `hideProgress()`.
3. An action to be taken based on the result, for example: Navigate to
   new Activity or Toast "Wrong Username/Passowrd".

//LoginActivity

```
@Override
public void showProgress() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void hideProgress() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

// LoginPresenter

```
    public void onLoginClicked() {

    String username = view.getUsername();
    if (username.isEmpty()){
        view.showUsernameError();
        view.hideProgress();
        return;
    }

    String password = view.getPassword();
    if (password.isEmpty()){
        view.showPasswordError();
        view.hideProgress();
        return;
    }

    view.showProgress();
    service.login(username,password, this);

}

@Override
public void isUserLoggedIn() {
    if(sharedPrefManager.isLoggedIn())
        view.navigateHome();
}

// implementing onFinished from FinishedListiner interface, to capture the result
@Override
public void onFinished(boolean bool) {
    view.hideProgress();

    if (bool){
        sharedPrefManager.userLogin(view.getUsername());
        view.navigateHome();
        return;
    }

    view.showLoginError();
}
```

// Service, which will connect to the datasource

```
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginContract.Service {

UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public void login(final String username, final String password, final FinishedListiner listener) {
    userRepository = UserRepositoryImpl.getInstance();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // The method which will be used in the presenter class.
            listener.onFinished(userRepository.checkUser(username, password));
        }
    }, 1200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below snippet :

Step 1:- Create BaseActivity extend to AppCompactActivity

Step 2:-Setting BaseActivity as per your requirement

Step 3:-Create Instance of your **Progress Dialog**

Step 4:-Create function showProgress()

Like:-

```
private fun showProgress(){
if(!progress.isShowing){
progress.show()
}
}
```

Step 5:- Create function HideProgress()

Like:-

```
private fun hideProgress(){
    if(progress.isShowing){
    progress.dismiss()
    }
    }
```

And use as per your requirement.

Comment: this function are already implemented in the View part (Model-View-Presendted).

Comment: i just updated the question with the implementation part.

Answer (score 0):

Your View just run presenter on another thread. See your Handler. Then it update the view and can not access to the UI. To fix this, just make sure your showProgress() is doing work on UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //show your proress here.
    }
});
```